# What happens to a PendingIntent if the target app was force-closed?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm actually working on an app that should post a notification 5 days in the future.

Using AlarmManager, I send a PendingIntent to my Receiver class.
Everything works fine until I force close my app. In this case, the notification doesn't appear.

So my question:
What happens to this PendingIntent, which was fired and did not reach its target?
When my app is finally restarted, can I check for PendingIntents, that did not reach its target?

**EDIT 1:**

These are the essential parts of my Broadcast Receiver:

```
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (context != null && intent?.action != null) {
            when (intent.action) {
                INTENT_ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED -> handleDeviceBoot()
                INTENT_ACTION_REMINDER -> handleReminder(context, intent.getLongExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_ID, -1))
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun schedule(context: Context, itemId: Long, fireDate: LocalDateTime) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        AlarmManagerCompat.setAndAllowWhileIdle(
            getAlarmManager(context),
            AlarmManager.RTC,
            fireDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli(),
            makePendingIntent(context, itemId)
        )

        with(AppDatabase.get(context).reminderDao()) {
            val oldReminder = getItemReminder(itemId)

            if (oldReminder == null) {
                insert(Reminder(itemId = itemId, fireDate = fireDate))
            } else {
                update(Reminder(id = oldReminder.id, itemId = itemId, fireDate = fireDate))
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun cancel(context: Context, itemId: Long) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val reminderDao = AppDatabase.get(context).reminderDao()
        val reminder = reminderDao.getItemReminder(itemId)

        reminder?.let {
            getAlarmManager(context).cancel(makePendingIntent(context, itemId))
            reminderDao.delete(it)
        }
    }

    private fun getAlarmManager(context: Context) = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    private fun makePendingIntent(context: Context, itemId: Long): PendingIntent {
        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, ReminderManager::class.java).apply {
            action = INTENT_ACTION_REMINDER
            putExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_ID, itemId)
        }
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, itemId.toInt(), alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @Viewed Yes, I implemented a similar logic to how WorkManager does it. I schedule a PendingIntent with expiration in 10 years, and at every app start, I check if that Intent still exists. If yes, I know that the app wasn't force-stopped. If the Intent doesn't exist, I use a database to "remember" my currently scheduled events, and reschedule them as well as the 10-year-PendingIntent. You can find my implementation there: https://github.com/guger/MoneyBook/blob/main/app/src/main/java/at/guger/moneybook/scheduler/reminder/ForceStopWorker.kt

Comment: I tried it. `PendingIntent` still exist after force stop occurs (with flag `FLAG_NO_CREATE` intent isn't null on the next launch app).

Comment: With force-stopped do you mean: Closing the app in the application drawer or do you force close it in the application info screen?

Comment: in settings device or terminate through Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is short: Active PendingIntents are cancelled on an application force-stop.

Answer (score 0):

As defined in [Official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent)

A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.

Revisit your code to check if there is anything else that would be causing this issue.

Comment: So if my app was killed and the pending intent was fired before the app was restarted, the PendingIntent should arrive on app start?

Comment: Please have a look at my edits...

And: Do I have to aquire a WakeLock here?

Comment: I had a look at the dumpsys alarm log, and it looks like the system reschedules the alarm after a force stop - restart of the app weirdly.

Comment: I actually tested what happenes to an alarm, if you force close the app and I came to the solution, that the alarm is deleted when the app is force stopped. Is there a way to check (during the next launch) if the app was force stopped?

Answer (score 0):

When you "force close" an application, the application gets set to the "stopped state". In the "stopped state" your application will NOT be automatically started by Android until the user manually restarts the application. This means that if you "force close" your app, your app will not receive any broadcast `Intent`s until it is manually restarted by the user.

I expect (although I have not tried it myself), that if you schedule an alarm to go off at time X and before time X you "force close" the app, when time X happens, the alarm manager will try to send the `PendingIntent`, however Android will refuse to actually execute the `BroadcastReceiver` because the app is in the "stopped state". In this case I expect the trigger is lost. Android will not retry or reschedule it.

Basically, when a user "force close"s an app, he is telling Android that he doesn't want that app to run anymore, including any background processes that the app might have, or want to start in the future.

Comment: Please have a look at my EDIT 2, what else should this be?

Comment: Are you using `WorkManager`? The only reference I could find to `ACTION_FORCE_STOP_RESCHEDULE` is in the source code for `WorkManager`

Comment: I used it, but it's possible this is from WorkManager. So all in all, I'll have to reschedule it if the App is reopened after a force stop?

Comment: That's correct. After force-stop your alarm may or may not be set (depending on whether or not it has already triggered).

Comment: So if it has been triggered, it will not be set, but if it is still running, it should be reset and triggered at the correct time?

Comment: I actually tested what happenes to an alarm, if you force close the app and I came to the solution, that the alarm is deleted when the app is force stopped. Is there a way to check (during the next launch) if the app was force stopped?

Comment: No, there is no way to tell that your app has been forced stopped.